# Custom Model Field required=False on ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following custom model field:

```
script = S3EnabledFileField(bucket=settings.MEDIA_BUCKET, upload_to=...)
```

In my forms.py, I am using a ModelForm:

```
class CreateProductionForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)

class Meta:
    model = Production
    fields = ('name', 'script')
```

This makes `script` a required form field. How would I make script an optional field (I don't know how to define a form field for the customized model field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the change to the model and not the form, and add `blank=True`:

```
script = S3EnabledFileField(bucket=settings.MEDIA_BUCKET, upload_to=..., blank=True)
```